# Does laravel have global variables?

Tags: cookies, laravel-4, global-variables

In laravel documentation i saw:

```
"You may also share a piece of data across all views:"

View::share('name', 'Steve');
```

So i thought this is was like a cookie (or global variable). That $test could be accessed in every view when the user is logged in. But this does not seem to be the case.

Does laravel have a function that acts like a cookies or global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you still have `$_SERVER` and `$_COOKIE` available. although you now have wrappers for those. for instance for `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` you'd use `Request::server('HTTP_USER_AGENT')`. whereas [cookies](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#cookies) have their own wrapper `Cookie::get()`.

the `View::share()` is simply to have variables available within all withs, that may be included within the main view. laravel does this for instance with `$errors`, that is available everytime you use `View::make()`, but might be empty.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

If it's something you need to access in multiple places you can use [`Config`](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration)?

Comment: This should be comment, you have enough reputation though.

Comment: I am using jquery mobile and laravel. I have 5 mobile views and need to make a back button. So i need laravel to use global variables that can be accesed trought the whole application. :D Now laravel keeps saaying (if i press the back button) that am missing a variable that is used in the last page.